# how to render multiple jade templates

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to understand how JADE works when there are several templates.

I worked by this tutorial:
http://www.franz-enzenhofer.com/jade

But, I got this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000
<h1> <a href="http://www.franz-enzenhofer.com/">Franz Enzenhofer</a></h1>
```

It seems that the command "res.render('index.jade',..." only took the index.jade template, but didn't insert it into the layout.jade template as should happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `partials`. They were [removed](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) with express v3. See the View System Changes part for more information.

From express v3 on you should use blocks. For [example](http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/):

my-template.jade:

```
extends my-layout

block head
  script(src="myfile.js")

block content
  h1 My page
```

my-layout.jade

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title My title
    block head
  body
    #content
      block content
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Unfortunately I find no way to contact the author of that demo in order to ask him to upgrade his demo.